# Realistic planetary terrain generation with weights

Tags: procedural-generation, terrain, planet

I need terrain generation for a planet. The planet will be divided up into several hundred hexes, and I need it to be realistic and based on weights. I have dabbled in terrain generation before, but nothing like this. So I figure it would be a good idea to ask the community for answers, recommended articles or the like.

By realistic, I mean not just random hexes, but continent shaped things with a few islands. More desert around the equator and more ice around the poles.

I also have two weights I need to base it around: ice percentage and water percentage. That means that around XX% of the planet will need to be water.

Does anyone have any advice or places to start? Generating arbitrary terrain is easy, but something a bit more "organic" like this seems rather difficult.

It also needs to be seamless. Should be obvious since it's a planet, but no harm in pointing it out.

Comment: You can start with the many questions in the [tag:procedural-generation] tag, such as [Huge procedurally generated 'wilderness' worlds](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4628/huge-procedurally-generated-wilderness-worlds)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As with most terrain generation, noise functions are your friend - Perlin and/or simplex noise in particular. I've implemented some planetary terrain generation algorithms and although they are in 2d, the resulting height / "texture" map could be projected to a sphere rather easily. I assume conversion to hex format is not an issue either.

My technique has been creating multiple noise layers, e.g. temperature and humidity. Temperature is fused with a latitude coordinate, in order to make the equator more hot and poles cold, while the noise makes sure it's not a simple gradient. The final terrain type is selected by rules like "if hot and not humid then pick desert". You can see my JavaScript implementation of this here: https://github.com/tapio/infiniverse/blob/master/js/universe/planet-aerial.js

As for the water percentage, you can just adjust the water level height as noise functions tend to have a constant average. Another option is to apply an exponent filter (useful also when generating clouds, [see my implementation here](https://github.com/tapio/infiniverse/blob/master/js/utils.js#L86)).

Another way to generate spherical terrain that came into mind (haven't tested) is to use 3d noise and sample it from a surface of a sphere, using the resulting value as the ground height at that point. You can then weight that according to amount of water on planet and the latitude coordinate.

I'll end with a link to one practical implementation of 3d planetary terrain generation: http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/tutorials/tutorial8.html